# How to calculate the points based on the price of the total purchase in django models?

Tags: django, database, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create points earned by users after buying something and placed an order from the frontend. Also, I need to save the points on the database because users later use that points to buy something.

The points system looks like this.

```
Point System for % of the total purchase
Upto 10,000 = 1 %
10k to 50k =2.75%
50K plus = 5%
```

I haven't saved the price in DB, I just used it as a property so that it remains safe and cant be changed by anyone. It calculates whenever the get or post API is called.

```
 class Order(models.Model):
        ORDER_STATUS = (
            ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
            ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
            ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
        )
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)    
        order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')
        ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)  



    @property
    def total_price(self):
        # abc = sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])
        # print(abc)
        return sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class OrderItem(models.Model):   
    orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12, editable=False, default=id_generator)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)


ORDER_STATUS = (
    ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
    ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
    ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
)
order_item_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

@property
def price(self):
    total_item_price = self.quantity * self.order_variants.price
    return total_item_price
```

**Updated Code:**

```
class Points(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    points_gained = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def collect_points(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            if instance.total_price <= 10000:
                abc = 0.01* (instance.total_price)
            else:
                abc = 0.75 * (instance.total_price)
            return abc

    post_save.connect(collect_points,sender=Order)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.points_gained = self.collect_points()
        super(Points, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried using Django signals and overwrite save function to create points. But when I check db, there are no rows in points table although order is made.

**OrderCreate API**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    #total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_total_price')
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','ordered_date','order_status', 'ordered', 'order_items', 'total_price', 'billing_details']
        # depth = 1

   

   
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.is_seller:
            order_items = validated_data.pop('order_items')
            billing_details = validated_data.pop('billing_details')
            order = Order.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
            BillingDetails.objects.create(user=user,order=order,**billing_details)
            for order_items in order_items:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,**order_items)

            
            order.save()
            return order
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a customer account.Please login as customer.")
```

Comment: Does a user get points per purchase or points per purchase amount?

Comment: points per perchase amount. I have mentioned how much points each gets for each purchase amount?? Can you help me on this??

Comment: I wouldn't recommend not saving the price. If a product's price ever changes, it looks like the user paid that amount, which is not true.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a post save signal for an order creation and there I would update the user's points. Those points can be saved on the user model (if you have custom user model), otherwise create a separate model for the points and add a one to one field to the User.

Comment: I have a custom user model, but how to save the points in the custom user model after calculating the price in Order model?? Can you write something (code) and show me as an example??

Comment: Hello @Vincent I have updated the code, can you please check it??

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the comments and updated code.

I would have a relationship between the user and the points model, as the points belong to a user and not an order. Also this enables you to update the points whenever the same user orders again.

This results in the following model and post save signal:

```
def update_points(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.total_price <= 10000:
            points_gained = 0.01 * instance.total_price
        else:
            points_gained = 0.75 * instance.total_price

        try:
            # Check if user already has points and update if so
            points = Points.objects.get(user=instance.user)
            points.points_gained = points_gained
            points.save(update_fields=['points_gained'])
        except Points.DoesNotExist:
            # User does not have points yet, create points
            Points.objects.create(user=instance.user,
                                  points_gained=points_gained)


post_save.connect(update_points, sender=Order)


class Points(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    points_gained = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Hello @Vincent, I tried your code but when I check my db, points_gained is 0 everytime as if  the code after except Points.DoesNotExist: Can you check once again please?

Comment: @SPDjango is the points object created after creating an order?

Comment: Yes the Point object is created but the points_gained value is zero.

Comment: If the points object is created and the value for points_gained is 0, it means the logic you have to calculate the amount of points, is resulting in 0. So `points_gained = 0.01 * instance.total_price` or `points_gained = 0.75 * instance.total_price` is 0. `sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])` is 0 somehow. Try debugging that.

Comment: I calculated the sum and saved it in the order field and it is not zero as i call the orderdetails api, i can see the price. Now what I perceive is that Order is created before creating OrderItem api, so initially a signal is passed when there is no OrderItem object created. Can you check my Order create api?  you will know.